# Is a return false required inside a function in this case

Tags: php

In my php function below, I return an error message on failure. Is it necessary I also return false? Because I then use the function like in the code below it.

**Function**

```
function addThis($a) {
    global $msg;

    if($a == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $msg = 'Error';
        //return false; -> Should I compulsorily be using return false here
    }
}
```

**Usage of the above function**

If it's false, it works fine and displays the error message. But since false isn't being returned from the function, will there be a chance that things might go wrong? Should I compulsorily use return false inside the function?

```
if (addThis(12)) {
    echo 'Cool';
} else {
    echo $msg;
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, always return something that you define. If you don't the effect on the calling code might be unpredictable.

Comment: if youre expecting `false` data type upon error, then you should

Comment: you should return $msg, and don't use global

Answer (score 2):

It will work without it, but adding it won't hurt, and would definitely be considered better stye, since it makes your intention clear, and means that the function consistently returns a boolean value.

The reason it works without it is that if PHP reaches the end of a function without hitting a `return` statement (or if you say `return;` with no value), the function is considered to return `null`. When you subsequently test that value in an `if` statement, it is cast to a boolean, and treated as `false`, thus reaching the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

> But since false isn't being returned from the function, will there be a chance  that things might go wrong?

No, it won't, provided the function definition is the same as you've shown in the question. Since there is nothing else after the `else` section, nothing will go wrong in this case.

However, it is considered best practice to `return` from a function and then use that in a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code you provided seems having no problem as such; as PHP is broad minded and doesn't mind these ignorable technicalities. But it is the `best practice` for a `Boolean Function` to `return` at least `True/False in any condition`.

> This way the function will perform two sidedly;
>
> ```
>    first:   will show a message "Error"
>    second:  will return false (behind the screen) function-wise; and will eradicate the error possibility with other functions
> ```

```
function addThis($a) {
    global $msg;

    if($a == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $msg = 'Error';
        return false;     // Yes, recommended that you should use "return false;" here
                          // Without "return false;" it can create problems when using with other functions
                          // BUT IT IS NOT COMPULSORY
    }
}
```